# Host to host multiple WCF services in same website in IIS 7.5?

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis-7.5

How would I host 2 WCF services within the same web site ( i.e. same web application) ? I do not want to have each WCF with its own independent web site host.

Answer (score 0):

WCF Services integration with IIS uses a .svc file for hosting in a web application.

You can create as many .svc files as services you created with WCF in the same web application, so you only need to create a .svc file for each WCF service inside your web project.

Maybe you could explain the implementation details services to know if this applies to you.

Comment: Ok. How about the service config. Will all config for all WCFs be under the same <system.serviceModel> section ?

Comment: Yes it's all below the same serviceModel section and also it uses the same endpoint, under the same address (managed by IIS), you can access any .svc services.

Comment: Sorry the first comment was wrong explained.Yes it's all below the same serviceModel section, you define one endpoint for each service, under the address managed by IIS, IIS handles the access and activation of endpoints via .svc files.